# Can we put some computation task inside setup method of mapper class in mapreduce code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apriori

I have used setup() method inside mapper class. There is also a user defined method aprioriGenK() defined in mapper class and invoked in map() method.

Now the problem is: whatever I know map method called for each line of input. Suppose there are 100 lines then this method called for 100 times. map method called aprioriGenK method each time accordingly. But there is no need to call aprioriGenK inside map method each time when map method called. i.e. result of aprioriGenK method is common of all line of input for map method. aprioriGenK method is very cpu intensive so it increases the computation time when called again and again. Can we manage somehow to call aprioriGenK a single time and use it in map method each time.
I have tried to keep aprioriGen inside setup method so that it can be called only one time but surprisingly it slow the execution to a great extent.

Here is my code:

```
import dataStructuresV2.ItemsetTrie;

public class AprioriTrieMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public static enum State
    {
        UPDATED
    }

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text itemset = new Text();

    private Configuration conf;
    private StringTokenizer fitemset;   // store one line of previous output file of frequent itemsets
    private ItemsetTrie trieLk_1 = null;    // prefix tree to store candidate (k-1)-itemsets of previous pass
    private int k;                      // itemsetSize or iteration no.
//  private ItemsetTrie trieCk = null;          // prefix tree to store candidate k-itemsets

    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        conf = context.getConfiguration();
        URI[] previousOutputURIs = Job.getInstance(conf).getCacheFiles();
        k = conf.getInt("k", k);
        trieLk_1 = new ItemsetTrie();

        for (URI previousOutputURI : previousOutputURIs)
        {
            Path previousOutputPath = new Path(previousOutputURI.getPath());
            String previousOutputFileName = previousOutputPath.getName().toString();
            filterItemset(previousOutputFileName, trieLk_1);
        }
    //  trieCk = aprioriGenK(trieLk_1, k-1);    // candidate generation from prefix tree of size k-1
    }// end method setup

    //trim count from each line and store only itemset
    private void filterItemset(String fileName, ItemsetTrie trieLk_1)
    {
        try 
        {
          BufferedReader fis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
          String line = null;
        //  trieLk_1 = new ItemsetTrie();

          while ((line = fis.readLine()) != null)
          {
              fitemset = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");
              trieLk_1.insertCandidateItemset(fitemset.nextToken());
          }
          fis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
          System.err.println("Caught exception while parsing the cached file '" + fileName + "' : " + StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe));
        }
    }// end method filterItemset

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        StringTokenizer items = new StringTokenizer(value.toString().toLowerCase()," \t\n\r\f,.:;?![]'"); // tokenize transaction
        LinkedList <String>itemlist = new LinkedList<String>(); // store the tokens or itemse of transaction

        LinkedList <String>listCt;      // list of subset of transaction that are candidates
    //  Map <String, Integer>mapCt;     // list of subset of transaction that are candidates with support count
        ItemsetTrie trieCk = null;          // prefix tree to store candidate k-itemsets
        StringTokenizer candidate;

        trieCk = aprioriGenK(trieLk_1, k-1);        // candidate generation from prefix tree of size k-1

        if(trieCk.numberOfCandidate() > 0)
            context.getCounter(State.UPDATED).increment(1);     // increment counter

        // optimization: if transaction size is less than candidate size then it should not be checked
        if(items.countTokens() >= k)
        {
            while (items.hasMoreTokens())               // add tokens of transaction to list
                itemlist.add(items.nextToken());

            // we use either simple linkedlist listCt or map mapCt
            listCt = trieCk.candidateSupportCount1(itemlist, k);
            for(String listCtMember : listCt)   // generate (key, value) pair. work on listCt
            {
                candidate = new StringTokenizer(listCtMember, "\n");
                if(candidate.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                    itemset.set(candidate.nextToken()); context.write(itemset, one);
                }
            }
        } // end if
    } // end method map

    // generating candidate prefix tree of size k using prefix tree of size k-1
    public ItemsetTrie aprioriGenK(ItemsetTrie trieLk_1, int itemsetSize)   // itemsetSize of trie Lk_1
    {
        ItemsetTrie candidateTree = new ItemsetTrie();      // local prefix tree store candidates k-itemsets
        trieLk_1.candidateGenK(candidateTree, itemsetSize); // new candidate prefix tree obtained
        return candidateTree;                               // return prefix tree of size k
    } // end method aprioriGenK
} //end class TrieBasedSPCItemsetMapper
```

Here is my driver class:

public class AprioriTrie
{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AprioriTrie.class);

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

//  String minsup = "1";
    String minsup = null;
    List<String> otherArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i < args.length; ++i)
    {
        if ("-minsup".equals(args[i]))
            minsup = args[++i];
        else
            otherArgs.add(args[i]);
    }

    conf.set("min_sup", minsup);

    log.info("Started counting 1-itemset ....................");
    Date date; long startTime, endTime;                         // for recording start and end time of job
    date = new Date(); startTime = date.getTime();              // starting timer

    // Phase-1
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "AprioriTrie: Iteration-1");
    job.setJarByClass(aprioriBasedAlgorithms.AprioriTrie.class);

    job.setMapperClass(OneItemsetMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(OneItemsetCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(OneItemsetReducer.class);

//  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);
    NLineInputFormat.setNumLinesPerSplit(job, 10000);   // set specific no. of line of records

//  Path inputPath = new Path("hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/user/hduser/sample-transactions1/");
    Path inputPath = new Path(otherArgs.get(0));
//  Path outputPath = new Path("hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/user/hduser/AprioriTrie/fis-1");
    Path outputPath = new Path(otherArgs.get(1)+"/fis-1");

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);            

    if(job.waitForCompletion(true))
        log.info("SUCCESSFULLY- Completed Frequent 1-itemsets Geneation.");
    else
        log.info("ERROR- Completed Frequent 1-itemsets Geneation.");

    // Phase-k >=2
    int iteration = 1; long counter;
    do
    {
        Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
        conf2.set("min_sup", minsup);
        conf2.setInt("k", iteration+1);

        log.info("Started counting "+(iteration+1)+"-itemsets ..................");
        Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2, "AprioriTrie: Iteration-"+(iteration+1));
        job2.setJarByClass(aprioriBasedAlgorithms.AprioriTrie.class);

        job2.setMapperClass(AprioriTrieMapper.class);
        job2.setCombinerClass(ItemsetCombiner.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(ItemsetReducer.class);

        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job2.setNumReduceTasks(4); // break the output in 3 files

        job2.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);
        NLineInputFormat.setNumLinesPerSplit(job2, 10000);

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000"), conf2);
    //  FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/user/hduser/AprioriTrie/fis-"+iteration+"/"));
        FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path(otherArgs.get(1)+"/fis-"+iteration));
        for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++)
        {
            job2.addCacheFile(status[i].getPath().toUri()); // add all files inside output fis
            //job2.addFileToClassPath(status[i].getPath());
        }

    //  input is same for these job
    //  outputPath = new Path("hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/user/hduser/AprioriTrie/fis-"+(iteration+1));
        outputPath = new Path(otherArgs.get(1)+"/fis-"+(iteration+1));

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job2, inputPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, outputPath);

        if(job2.waitForCompletion(true))
            log.info("SUCCESSFULLY- Completed Frequent "+(iteration+1)+"-itemsets Generation.");
        else
            log.info("ERROR- Completed Frequent "+(iteration+1)+"-itemsets Generation.");

        iteration++;
        counter = job2.getCounters().findCounter(AprioriTrieMapper.State.UPDATED).getValue();
    } while (counter > 0);

    date = new Date(); endTime = date.getTime();                    //end timer
    log.info("Total Time (in milliseconds) = "+ (endTime-startTime));
    log.info("Total Time (in seconds) = "+ (endTime-startTime)*0.001F);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add that function call to the run method of your mapper just after the setup call.This will ensure that your method will only be called once per mapper.

```
public class Mymapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> 
{
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException
    {
               //do something

    }
    public void myfunc(String parm)
    {
        System.out.println("parm="+parm);
    }
    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        setup(context);
        myfunc("hello");
        while(context.nextKeyValue())
        {
            map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: am not used to use run method yet and dont know how to make it in driver class. I have added my driver class in modified question. I need help to invoke in driver class also.

Comment: @SudhakarSingh You don't need to add anything in the driver class. Just add that to your mapper class by replacing myfunc() with your function name, so that it would be called after your setup method and just before it invokes to read from the Inputformat.

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to my mapper class but the resulting code is extremely slow and it seems it makes multiple calls to `aprioriGenK()`.

Here is my modified code.

```
public class AprioriTrieMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
public static enum State
{
    UPDATED
}

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text itemset = new Text();

private Configuration conf;
private StringTokenizer fitemset;   // store one line of previous output file of frequent itemsets
private ItemsetTrie trieLk_1 = null;    // prefix tree to store candidate (k-1)-itemsets of previous pass
private int k;                      // itemsetSize or iteration no.
private ItemsetTrie trieCk = null;          // prefix tree to store candidate k-itemsets

public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    conf = context.getConfiguration();
    URI[] previousOutputURIs = Job.getInstance(conf).getCacheFiles();
    k = conf.getInt("k", k);
    trieLk_1 = new ItemsetTrie();

    for (URI previousOutputURI : previousOutputURIs)
    {
        Path previousOutputPath = new Path(previousOutputURI.getPath());
        String previousOutputFileName = previousOutputPath.getName().toString();
        filterItemset(previousOutputFileName, trieLk_1);
    }
//  trieCk = aprioriGenK(trieLk_1, k-1);    // candidate generation from prefix tree of size k-1
}// end method setup

//trim count from each line and store only itemset
private void filterItemset(String fileName, ItemsetTrie trieLk_1)
{
    try 
    {
      BufferedReader fis = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
      String line = null;
    //  trieLk_1 = new ItemsetTrie();

      while ((line = fis.readLine()) != null)
      {
          fitemset = new StringTokenizer(line, "\t");
          trieLk_1.insertCandidateItemset(fitemset.nextToken());
      }
      fis.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
      System.err.println("Caught exception while parsing the cached file '" + fileName + "' : " + StringUtils.stringifyException(ioe));
    }
}// end method filterItemset

//run method
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    setup(context);
    trieCk = aprioriGenK(trieLk_1, k-1);    // candidate generation from prefix tree of size k-1

    if(trieCk.numberOfCandidate() > 0)
        context.getCounter(State.UPDATED).increment(1);     // increment counter

    while(context.nextKeyValue())
    {
        map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
    }
}// end method run

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    StringTokenizer items = new StringTokenizer(value.toString().toLowerCase()," \t\n\r\f,.:;?![]'"); // tokenize transaction
    LinkedList <String>itemlist = new LinkedList<String>(); // store the tokens or itemse of transaction

    LinkedList <String>listCt;      // list of subset of transaction that are candidates
//  Map <String, Integer>mapCt;     // list of subset of transaction that are candidates with support count
//  ItemsetTrie trieCk = null;          // prefix tree to store candidate k-itemsets
    StringTokenizer candidate;

//  if(context.getCounter(State.UPDATED).getValue() == 0)
//  {
//      trieCk = aprioriGenK(trieLk_1, k-1);    // candidate generation from prefix tree of size k-1

    //  if(trieCk.numberOfCandidate() > 0)
        //  context.getCounter(State.UPDATED).increment(1);     // increment counter
//  }

    // optimization: if transaction size is less than candidate size then it should not be checked
    if(items.countTokens() >= k)
    {
        while (items.hasMoreTokens())               // add tokens of transaction to list
            itemlist.add(items.nextToken());

        // we use either simple linkedlist listCt or map mapCt
        listCt = trieCk.candidateSupportCount1(itemlist, k);
        for(String listCtMember : listCt)   // generate (key, value) pair. work on listCt
        {
            candidate = new StringTokenizer(listCtMember, "\n");
            if(candidate.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                itemset.set(candidate.nextToken()); context.write(itemset, one);
            }
        }
    } // end if
} // end method map

// generating candidate prefix tree of size k using prefix tree of size k-1
public ItemsetTrie aprioriGenK(ItemsetTrie trieLk_1, int itemsetSize)   // itemsetSize of trie Lk_1
{
    ItemsetTrie candidateTree = new ItemsetTrie();      // local prefix tree store candidates k-itemsets
    trieLk_1.candidateGenK(candidateTree, itemsetSize); // new candidate prefix tree obtained
    return candidateTree;                               // return prefix tree of size k
} // end method aprioriGenK
} //end class TrieBasedSPCItemsetMapper
```